# Getting wrong output in finding indexes of set bits - c++

Tags: c++

I have written below code in C++ for finding indexes of set bits in numbers.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    for(ll i = 1; i < (1<<3); i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<" here ";
        for(ll j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(i&(1<<j) != 0)
                cout<<j<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output which I am getting is (which is wrong):

```
1 here 0 1 2
2 here
3 here 0 1 2
4 here
5 here 0 1 2
6 here
7 here 0 1 2
```

whereas, if we take `i = 1`. Since, binary representation of 1 is `001`, so on doing bitwise `&` with `010` i.e 2, it should give `0`. Therefore, for i = 1, only `0` should get printed, `1 here 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to operator precedence, you need to use

```
if ((i & (1 << j)) != 0)
```

Not the extra parens around the `&` operator.